# QXML - Are children accessed sequentialy

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qtxml

I have, lets say, the following XML:

```
<geometry>
    <point x=0 y=0/.
    <point x=1 y=1/.
    <point x=2 y=2/.
</geometry>
```

And I have the following code:

```
QFile file(...);
QDomDocument dom;
dom.setContent(&file);
QDomElement geometry = dom.documentElement();
for( int i=0; i<geometry.childNodes().size(); ++i ) {
    std::cout << childNodes().item(i).toElement().attribute("x").toDouble() << std::endl;
}
```

Is it guaranted that my output will always be that below?

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, because `QDomNodeList` returned by `childNodes` implements [W3C's NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-536297177) which is ordered.